# Is there a way I can programmatically attach a large file to an outlook message despite it exceeding the server size limit?

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin, email-attachments, .net-4.8

**A quick note in case you come upon this question hoping for a solution.... there isn't one. Sadly sometimes one has to accept that the right answer to one's question is "You can't do that".**

I am hoping there is something I can do here to ensure that attaching a large file to an Outlook.MailItem works exactly the same as doing so manually.

To be precise... when a user composes an email in Outlook and they attach a file that is too large to the email, Outlook will happily attach the file to the email. Instead of simply refusing to do so, it will attach the file and a message will appear in the Inspector:
[image: Composing a message and adding an attachment that is way too big]

However....

When coding a similar action you would get access to an Outlook.MailItem and you would invoke the .Add method on its .Attachments object

```
oMailObject.Attachments.Add("<path to a file that is way too big here>")
```

The problem is that that action fails. An error is thrown
"The file you're attaching is bigger than the server allows. Try putting the file in a shared location and sending a link instead."

Yes, we can obviously catch the error and then show a message to the user. That's what we're currently doing. It would, however, be nicer if there were a way I can prevent it from raising the error so it would still attach the file to the MailItem, and then when I show the inspector to the user they would see the same thing they would see if they had attached the attachment manually.

Is there an option on the MailItem to prevent it raising an error? Something in the Attachments.Add method? Any suggestions?

Comment: Reason I am asking.... If we can make the mailitem appear to the user as in my image, the user will naturally blame outlook, the outlook server, and contact their IT support. Which is brilliant. Because when we show the message as we currently do, even though it's Outlook causing the "problem" they don't do any of that. Instead, they contact US and they blame us for our *bleep*y Add-in "not working". The difference seems trivial. It isn't.

Comment: Understand why your trying to do what you doing, but feel you're not going to get too far as you're fighting environment constraints.  Perhaps well worded feedback to the user when the file is to large, then redirect them to alternatives like a drop box link or something would get around the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Attachments.Add` method doesn't provide anything for that.

You may consider adjusting the maximum size of the attachments in Outlook. Regular mail profiles can be configured using the windows registry keys.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\<x.0>\Outlook\Preferences
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\ x.0 \Outlook\Preferences
```

There you can add a value type: `DWORD`
Value name: `MaximumAttachmentSize`
Value data: An integer that specifies the total maximum allowable attachment size. For example, specify 30720 (Decimal) to configure a 30-MB limit. Specify a value of zero (0) if you want to configure no limit for attachments.

Exchange accounts require configuration on the Exchange side, read more about that in the [Microsoft Exchange Server email account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/attachment-size-exceeds-the-allowable-limit-error#microsoft-exchange-server-email-account) configuration section.

Comment: Hello Eugene, I wish I could accept two answers to the question. Sometimes the correct answer to a question is "it can't be done", as it is in this case. And while I obviously won't like that answer, it's the correct answer, so I have to accept one of the two answers. I was betwixt and between which one but in the end your answer does start by calling a spade a spade with "(the) method doesn't provide anything for that.".

Answer (score 1):

You can read `PR_MAX_SUBMIT_MESSAGE_SIZE` MAPI property (DASL name is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x666D0003"`) from the store (use `Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`) - it returns the size in kB - prior to sending the message. This property is Exchange-specific.

Comment: This sounds like a useful way to avoid the error. I'm not sure if it helps OP's goal of wanting to attaching the file even if it is too large, so that Outlook itself reports the error.

Comment: The check can be preformed when the file is added rather than when the message is sent, which is a lot more user-frieldly.

Comment: Yes, izzy is right. We actually do the add through a button on a form in a pane on the Inspector, while the user is composing the message, so before they try to send it. At the moment they click the button, pick the file they wish to attach from our system, and then this fails and we show a message. The user experiences this as OUR software failing. If the attachment had been added and then the user couldn't send it, they would experience that as OUTLOOK failing, and they wouldn't come to US looking for solutions...

Comment: Well, you can word the error message in a way that tells the user who is to blame: "Your Microsoft Exchange Server will not allow to send messages greater than blah. Click 'Cancel' to select a different file."

Comment: Yes, I know.... in fact the error message that Outlook itself raises is quite good: "The file you're attaching is bigger than the server allows. Try putting the file in a shared location and sending a link instead." - if we had users that actually bothered to READ such messages this message would be more than sufficient. But users don't work like that. They click a button that belongs to an add-in, an error message pops up, so "obviously" the add-in is to blame, no matter what the message says. That's what we have to deal with here.... *sigh* :-)

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I wish I could accept two answers to the question. Sometimes the correct answer to a question is "it can't be done", as it is in this case. And while I obviously won't like that answer, it's the correct answer, so I have to accept one of the two answers. I was betwixt and between which one but in the end Eugene's answer does start by calling a spade a spade with "(the) method doesn't provide anything for that.".